# getting an error to connecting mysql db in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling, connection

I am working on a new project and I am getting an error when I connect with my DB I don't know why it is happening my DB name and user name is all correct but why I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\treeview\treeview.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\treeview\treeview.php on line 9

Code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
mysql_select_db('test');
$qry = "SELECT * FROM treeview_items";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$arrayCategories = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arrayCategories[$row['id']] = array("parent_id" => $row['parent_id'], "name" => $row['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are on PHP 7+, which means that `mysql_query` is deprecated. Please use PDO or mysqli.

More info on that function's man page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the connection to your database through:

```
$connection = new mysqli($hostname, $db_username, $password, $db_name);
if ($connection->connect_error){
    $error = "Failed to connect to db: " . $connection->connect_error;
    // Do whatever you want with $error
}
$connection->query("SET NAMES utf8mb4"); // mostly, people use utf8 instead
```

Comment: I already did it, you just have to change the ```$db_username``` and ```$password``` and other arguments to achieve the connection. then you can try ```$connection ->query($your_query_goes_here)```

Comment: please let me know it's ok

Comment: $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'modern');
if ($connection->connect_error){
    $error = "Failed to connect to db: " . $connection->connect_error;
    // Do whatever you want with $error
}
$connection->query("SELECT * FROM treeview_items"); // mostly, people use utf8 instead
 $result=mysql_query($qry);


 $arrayCategories = array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
 $arrayCategories[$row['id']] = array("parent_id" => $row['parent_id'], "name" =>                       
 $row['name']);   
  }